# Not include header from CSV file in DataTables - Jquery

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins, datatables-1.10

I am using two plugins for JQuery library: csv2Table and dataTables. I am pulling data from flat file to populate dataTables and the header from CSV is being included in table as a row. I would like to remove the header row from appearing inside dataTable. I having tried removing this element from associative array by using shift and splice with little success. Any suggestions much appreciated.

```
// fetch csv data to populate dataTable
$.get("tbl.csv" + "?" + randomize(), function (data) {
    csv_contents = $.csv()( data );
    $('#container').html('<table cellpadding="1" cellspacing="1" border="1" class="display" id="container_tbl"></table>');  

    //column search
    oTable = $("#container_tbl").DataTable({
        "initComplete": function (settings, json){
            //alert("done loading");
        },
        "sPaginationType": "full_numbers",
        "aLengthMenu": [[10, 20, -1], [10, 20, "All"]],
        "iDisplayLength": 20,
        "aaData": csv_contents,
        "aoColumns": [
                        { "sTitle": "Title" },
                        { "sTitle": "Description" },
                        { "sTitle": "Format" },
                        { "sTitle": "Size" },
                        { "sTitle": "Type", "bVisible": true }

            ]
    });

    // filter table by type
    oTable.columns(4).search(asset).draw();

    // filter table by wg
    //oTable.columns().search(wg).draw();

    // filter table by term
    oTable.columns(1).search(wg).draw();
```

The first 5 characters from header being spread over 5 columns. For example,
Title | Description | Format | Size | Type
<        a            h        r      f

Comment: What does `csv_contents` look like? Not familiar with `$.csv()`. If it's an array should be able to do `csv_contents.shift()`

Comment: it's an associative array ie. an array of arrays

Comment: (424) [""Title","Description","Format","Size","Type"", Array(5), Array(5), Array(5), Array(5), Array(5), Array(5), Array(5), Array(5), Array(5), Array(5), Array(5), Array(5), Array(5), Array(5), Array(5), Array(5), Array(5), Array(5), Array(5), Array(5), Array(5), Array(5), Array(5), …]

Comment: There is a lot of `csv2Table` and `$.csv` implementations out there. What exactly are you using ...?

Comment: name: 'csv2table',
        version: '0.02-b-2.8',
        date: '2009.1.10',
        update: 'http://jsgt.org/lib/jquery/plugin/csv2table/v002/update.txt',
        ver: '<span class="csv2tableVersion" style="color:#aaa"></span><script>jQuery(function($){ $(".csv2tableVersion").html("version:csv2table-"+$.csv2table.version) })</script>',